# clang compile error using tuple with a single parameter

Tags: c++11, clang++

I don't understand why clang will not compile the following code but gcc does. No args or more than one arg to tuple works, a single arg does not.

```
   #include <tuple>

   int main(int , char *[])
   {
       // fails
       std::tuple<int> a;

       // works
       std::tuple<> b;
       std::tuple<int,int> c;
       return 0;
   }
```

The clang error

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 tuple.cpp 
In file included from tuple.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:483:62: error: pack
      expansion contains parameter packs '_Elements' and '_UElements' that have different lengths
      (1 vs. 0)
      return __and_<is_constructible<_Elements, _UElements&&>...>::value;
                                     ~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~   ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:631:21: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_TC<true,
      int>::_MoveConstructibleTuple<>' requested here
                    _MoveConstructibleTuple<_UElements...>()
                    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:636:19: note: while
      substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _UElements = <>]
        constexpr tuple(_UElements&&... __elements)
                  ^~~~~
tuple.cpp:5:21: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'tuple'
      [with _UElements = <>, $1 = (no value)]
    std::tuple<int> a;
                    ^
In file included from tuple.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:489:60: error: pack
      expansion contains parameter packs '_UElements' and '_Elements' that have different lengths
      (0 vs. 1)
      return __and_<is_convertible<_UElements&&, _Elements>...>::value;
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:633:21: note: in
      instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_TC<true,
      int>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<>' requested here
                    _ImplicitlyMoveConvertibleTuple<_UElements...>()
                    ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/6.1.1/../../../../include/c++/6.1.1/tuple:636:19: note: while
      substituting prior template arguments into non-type template parameter [with _UElements = <>]
        constexpr tuple(_UElements&&... __elements)
                  ^~~~~
tuple.cpp:5:21: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'tuple'
      [with _UElements = <>, $1 = (no value)]
    std::tuple<int> a;
                    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=24770

Comment: @DarkFalcon That seems to be it. Same version of clang with older gcc works on other machines. Thanks

Comment: @Adrian - Which version of clang++ are you using? My 3.5 compile without problem.

Comment: @max66 clang 3.7.1 with gcc 6.1.1 - works fine with 3.7.1 and gcc 5.2.0 - it seems it is a clang bug

Comment: @Adrian - Not sure to understand (my fault: I have big troubles with English; sorry). Are you saying that you have the error, with clang 3.7.1, when gcc 6.1.1 is installed but that clang 3.7.1 compile without error when is installed gcc 5.2.0? And I see that you're using `clang++ -std=c++14`, so I suspect a problem of interaction between clang++ and the libstdc++ that is installed together with g++ 6.1.1. Suggestion: install libc++ (if isn't installed) and try with libc++ (`clang++ -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ tuple.cpp`)

Comment: Read Dark Falcons comment. It is a clang bug with later version of gcc and libstdc++

Comment: I see this problem with icc (intel) in c++17 mode

Comment: In Intel's icpc (ICC) 19.1.1.219 20200306 in -std=c++17 in a system with g++ 9 I solved this by adding the option `-gxx-name=g++-8` to compile `<tuple>` code and avoid this error.